# Active Contour Models in OpenCV 3.0

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, contour

I'm trying to implement an Active Contour Models algorithm with Opencv 3.0 in C++.
This algorithm is based on a script I wrote for MatLab and is not working as it supposed to.
This two images shows the result of the two algorithms running.

The MatLab script:

[image]

and the OpenCV one:

[image]

In both of them I used the same values for all the ACM parameters, so they should be returning the same thing, the white circle contour.
I'm suspecting the problem is my image energy function, since gradient operations in opencv and matlab are not the same. The matlab script for the image energy is:

```
function [Eext] = get_eext(wl, we, wt, image)

%External Energy
[row,col] = size(image);
eline = image; %eline is simply the image intensities

[grady,gradx] = gradient(image);
eedge = -1 *(gradx .* gradx + grady .* grady);



%masks for taking various derivatives
m1 = [-1 1];
m2 = [-1;1];
m3 = [1 -2 1];
m4 = [1;-2;1];
m5 = [1 -1;-1 1];

cx = conv2(image,m1,'same');
cy = conv2(image,m2,'same');
cxx = conv2(image,m3,'same');
cyy = conv2(image,m4,'same');
cxy = conv2(image,m5,'same');

eterm = zeros(row, col);

for i = 1:row;
    for j= 1:col;
        % eterm as deined in Kass et al Snakes paper
        eterm(i,j) = (cyy(i,j)*cx(i,j)*cx(i,j) -2 *cxy(i,j)*cx(i,j)...
            *cy(i,j) + cxx(i,j)*cy(i,j)*cy(i,j))/((1+cx(i,j)*cx(i,j)...
            + cy(i,j)*cy(i,j))^1.5);
    end;
end;

Eext = (wl*eline + we*eedge + wt*eterm);
```

And in C++ my function turned out like this:

```
Mat get_eext(float wl, float we, float wt, Mat image){

Mat eline, gradx, grady, img_gray, eedge;

//bitdepth defined as CV_32F
image.convertTo(img_gray, bitdepth);

//Convolution Kernels
Mat m1, m2, m3, m4, m5;
m1 = (Mat_<float>(1, 2) << -1, 1);
m2 = (Mat_<float>(2, 1) << -1, 1);
m3 = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << 1, -2, 1);
m4 = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 1, -2, 1);
m5 = (Mat_<float>(2, 2) << 1, -1, -1, 1);

//cvtColor(image, img_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY); <- Not required since image already in grayscale
img_gray.copyTo(eline);

Mat kernelx = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << -0.5, 0, 0.5);
Mat kernely = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << -0.5, 0, 0.5);

filter2D(img_gray, gradx, -1, kernelx);
filter2D(img_gray, grady, -1, kernely);

//Edge Energy
eedge = -1 * (gradx.mul(gradx) + grady.mul(grady));

//Termination Energy Convolution
Mat cx, cy, cxx, cyy, cxy, eterm, cxm1, den, cxcx, cxcxm1, cxcxcy, cxcycxy, cycycxx;
filter2D(img_gray, cx, bitdepth, m1);
filter2D(img_gray, cy, bitdepth, m2);
filter2D(img_gray, cxx, bitdepth, m3);
filter2D(img_gray, cyy, bitdepth, m4);
filter2D(img_gray, cxy, bitdepth, m5);

//element wise operations to find Eterm
cxcx = cx.mul(cx);
cxcx.convertTo(cxcxm1, -1, 1, 1);
den = cxcxm1 + cy.mul(cy);
cv::pow(den, 1.5, den);
cxcxcy = cxcx.mul(cy);
cxcycxy = cx.mul(cy);
cxcycxy = cxcycxy.mul(cxy);
cycycxx = cy.mul(cy);
cycycxx = cycycxx.mul(cxx);
eterm = (cxcxcy - 2 * cxcycxy + cycycxx);
cv::divide(eterm,den,eterm,-1);

//Image energy
Mat eext;
eext = wl*eline + we*eedge + wt*eterm;
return eext;}
```

Does anyone knows what might be wrong?

Comment: did you compare your gradient image with the matlab gradient image?

Comment: `filter2D` performs **correlation** in OpenCV.  In MATLAB, `conv2` performs **convolution**.  The difference is that the kernel is **not** 180 degree rotated for `filter2D` where MATLAB does this.  If you want to achieve the same results for `filter2D` and OpenCV, you need to **rotate the kernel by 180 degrees** in OpenCV.  With regards to that, Micka is correct in that you should compare your gradient images.  They are probably not the same.  `imgradient` uses the Sobel kernel for the gradient so make sure your kernel is correct in OpenCV.

Comment: The gradient image are indeed different. By rotating 180 degrees you mean using [1 -1] instead of [-1 1]?

Comment: @Andrei Sorry to get back to you so late.  Yes that's correct.  In OpenCV, you can achieve a 180 degree rotation by transposing first, then flipping along the columns, so use `cv::transpose`, then `cv::flip` with the `flipCode` being set to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As asked by David Doria, here is the final version of the function get_eext after a few corrections. This version worked fine for me.

```
Mat config_eext(float wl, float we, float wt, Mat image)
{
Mat eline, gradx, grady, img_gray, eedge;

//bitdepth defined as CV_32F
image.convertTo(img_gray, bitdepth);

//Convolution Kernels
Mat m1, m2, m3, m4, m5;
m1 = (Mat_<float>(1, 2) << 1, -1);
m2 = (Mat_<float>(2, 1) << 1, -1);
m3 = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << 1, -2, 1);
m4 = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 1, -2, 1);
m5 = (Mat_<float>(2, 2) << 1, -1, -1, 1);

img_gray.copyTo(eline);

//Kernels de gradiente
Mat kernelx = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << -1, 0, 1);
Mat kernely = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << -1, 0, 1);

//Gradiente em x e em y
filter2D(img_gray, gradx, -1, kernelx);
filter2D(img_gray, grady, -1, kernely);

//Edge Energy como definido por Kass
eedge = -1 * (gradx.mul(gradx) + grady.mul(grady));

//Termination Energy Convolution
Mat cx, cy, cxx, cyy, cxy, eterm(img_gray.rows, img_gray.cols, bitdepth), cxm1, den, cxcx, cxcxm1, cxcxcy, cxcycxy, cycycxx;
filter2D(img_gray, cx, bitdepth, m1);
filter2D(img_gray, cy, bitdepth, m2);
filter2D(img_gray, cxx, bitdepth, m3);
filter2D(img_gray, cyy, bitdepth, m4);
filter2D(img_gray, cxy, bitdepth, m5);

//element wise operations to find Eterm
cxcx = cx.mul(cx);
cxcx.convertTo(cxcxm1, -1, 1, 1);
den = cxcxm1 + cy.mul(cy);
cv::pow(den, 1.5, den);
cxcxcy = cxcx.mul(cy);
cxcycxy = cx.mul(cy);
cxcycxy = cxcycxy.mul(cxy);
cycycxx = cy.mul(cy);
cycycxx = cycycxx.mul(cxx);
eterm = (cxcxcy - 2 * cxcycxy + cycycxx);
cv::divide(eterm, den, eterm, -1);

//Image energy
Mat eext;
eext = wl*eline + we*eedge + wt*eterm;
return eext;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the posting and it really helps. I have a question here, were you implementing the whole algorithm by yourself? I saw the parameters for active contour are different in OpenCV and Matlab. How did you corresponding those parameters from Matlab to OpenCV? Thanks!